# visual studio localhost run without calling api

Tags: c#, visual-studio, http

I dont know what is happening with my machine or visual studio but since yesterday every http project i open, even new ones, calls their own api endpoint.

for example this endpoint: `http://localhost:7071/api/Function1_HttpStart`
i dont make any api call and it runs in console whan i start the function.

My thoghts are that the ports on visual studio still open and i need to close them, but when i do `netstat –ab` in admin cmd i dont see the localhost i have opened.

Comment: Not sure of what the actual problem is, or how your answer would address it

Comment: I restarted my computer several times and it did not work untill i reset the network settings

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you ara using windows 10 go to -> Start -> search: network reset -> reset your network settings and then restart your computer, this should fix the issue.

Comment: I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, you can click '✔' to mark your reply as an answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.